# Three buttons in line -> resize to fit parent width

Tags: android, layout

I have this layout

- Linear Layout

  - Scroll View

    - Relative Layout

      - 9x Button

In View like this (3x3 Grid)

```
+---------+  
| o  o  o |  
| o  o  o |  
| o  o  o |
+---------+
```

Every button has it's background and no text, background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_btn1_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_btn1"/>
</selector>
```

How should I state the layout, so the buttons will be always 3 per line, and will resize so that they will fit the view ?

Comment: Looks like perfect place to use a TableLayout.

Comment: TableLayout within ScrollView on top of LinearLayout ?

Comment: TableLayout in ScrollView instead of RelativeLayout I'd rather say.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig put it in an answer, so I can accept it occasionaly

Comment: Just accept the one below. It says it all basically. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

UPDATE:

If you make LinearLayout (android:id="@+id/wrapper" (LOOK CODE BELOW)) with same layout_height and layout_width you will get what you want

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="300dp">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please look at screenshots. In second screenshot the LinearLayout with android:id="@+id/wrapper" have same width and height and equals 300dp

[image] [image]

Try it please! Hope it help you!!

Comment: It has the same issue as answer from Kasper. Buttons are resized horizontally but vertically the still on same height. Need to stretch them with same ratio to height like to width

Comment: Right, you did it, sorry for accepting answer so late :)) Thanks

Comment: Thank you dear. Your solution is very simple and intelligent!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick if you replace it with your mentioned `RelativeLayout`. All you need to do is ids and style:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: works almost perfectly, but my buttons are square shaped and their widths sum (3 x width) is longer than screen. using `layout_weight` i can stretch them automaticaly to fit the width, but the height isn't adjusted.

Comment: Provided that the `ScrollView` has a fixed height, you can change all the `android:layout_height` in my posted layout to `fill_parent` and they will stretch in height too. By all I mean them all, including the one in the outer `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Scroll view is fill_parent on both dimensions. and `android:layout_height` only on LinearLayout or on both (Layout and Buttons) ?

Comment: On both `LinearLayout` and `Buttons`.

Comment: Not working, check the code, if it is as you recommended please. http://pastebin.com/wU8nKWWr

Comment: It looks right - and should work like that. Only things I can suggest is that you set the height to a specific value that makes the button rectangular.

Comment: But that will be against the "automatic resize", which is why i laid down this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TableLayout` that fills the screen and nest it in a `ScrollView`. Then you can inflate programmatically 3 views in a `TableRow` and add that to `TableLayout`, like this you will get 3 views per row.
Repeat this 3 times and you got what you asked for.

Note that if you do that programmatically you can change the order of the buttons pretty easy

Good luck,
Arkde