# Great distribution of horizontal radio buttons

Tags: android, layout, radio-button

I have 3 RadioButton in one line (linearLayout). I want to distribute them properly in the line, and not align all of them to the left, just as in [this screenshot](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

Currently it is displayed like this:

[image]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Yes"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton3" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:checked="false"/>
            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Maybe"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:checked="true"/>
            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:checked="false"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It is possible for classic buttons with `0dp` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296915/three-buttons-in-line-resize-to-fit-parent-width)), but RadioButtons are invisible with this setting.

Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" android:checked="false"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Maybe"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton" android:checked="true"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:checked="false"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks ! I need to read more about `layout_weight`. :)

Comment: You can omit `android:weightSum="3"` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Then you must have to use layout weight on you radio button:-

[android:layout_weight beginner's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084185/androidlayout-weight-beginners-question)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:checked="false"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Maybe"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" android:checked="true"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="No"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" android:checked="false"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```