# Button not visible at the emulator using scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/MainParent"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="454dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80sp"
            android:text="Sim Card Master"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/pumpkinorange"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/simno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:text="Sim No"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/simName"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Service Provider"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/service_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/serviceprovid" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Unit Master"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/pumpkinorange"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:text="Unit No"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/unitNo"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="IMEI No"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/imeiNo"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vehicleNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Vehicle Master"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/pumpkinorange"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Vehicle No"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vehicleNo"
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know to correct this error. In xml layout i can see the button, but in the emulator its not visible or button not scrolled. also i want this two button in same line with left and right alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Specified inside scrollview second linearlayout as

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="454dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

change to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

You Specified height fixed that why it does't display...

```
<LinearLayout 

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"         
            >

                      <Button 
                android:id="@+id/login_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Login"
                />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Cancel"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wow.. thanks brother.. can you do another help. how to add the two buttons in the same line. in the above xml.

Comment: Hari i need atleast 10 reputation to post an image. I want button in same line. not one buy one. i think u understand.

Comment: ya i removed and do run. same result. u understand my question bro.

Comment: from your above layout inside two buttons are there you need that in horizontal correct...

Comment: Hari i do that. But the button position remains same one by one order only. Anyway u clear my doubt. If u could solve this error means much useful for me. exmaple [link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://i.stack.imgur.com/WAoeB.png&imgrefurl=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296915/three-buttons-in-line-resize-to-fit-parent-width&h=346&w=213&sz=13&tbnid=qgRi4QB8tjJ_qM:&tbnh=88&tbnw=54&zoom=1&usg=__6vIKopTKD-Jua8FRoMfHpMBrtNY=&docid=I2jL2JL2W5og3M&sa=X&ei=6z4TUrLbJYTOrQeMjoCADg&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAA&dur=298)

Comment: put linearlayout and orientation horizontal for particular two buttons only not for whole layout...

Comment: I do that one hari. But it will not come under scroll view. we cannot scroll the two buttons under this linear layout. Then only i delete that layout.

Comment: actually you don't want that button inside scrollview

Comment: no no i want inside only. If i doing like that u said means its output in the emulator get out of the screen. because the new linear layout will not come under the scroll view. so only i don't know how to get the new layout under the scroll view

Comment: Now i have edited.. Please check my edit.. Copy and paste the code in your question..

Comment: @Hari: I did a rollback to the original question. You must not edit the question to show the correct usage. That is why we have answers. How could anyone follow this thread if the question itself is correct?

Comment: Tobias kun can u help me to get out of from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set your ScrollView's height to `match_parent`

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Comment: ya that's also i tried before posting and now also once. same result. help me.